# Rowspan arrangement with coprime numbers

Tags: html, html-table

I have data (A, B1, B2, C1, C2 and C3) that I'd like to put in a table like this:

```
+----+----+----+
|    | B1 | C1 |
|    +----+    |
| A  | B2 +----|
|    +----+ C2 |
|    | B3 |    |
+----+----+----+
```

Using rowspans, I came up with this:

```
<table> 
<tr>
    <td rowspan=6>A</td>
    <td rowspan=2>B1</td>
    <td rowspan=3>C1</td>
</tr>
<tr><td rowspan=2>B2</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan=3>C2</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan=2>B3</td></tr>
</table>
```

But it doesn't work. I tried several combinations and variants, but neither of them work either.

I'd like a solution that works with any coprime numbers if possible (the example here is with 2 and 3).

I made a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/NPETb/ ) with this code if you want to hack it quickly yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rowspans add up to 6, but there aren't actually 6 rows in your table.

You need to add the rows which end up being empty as well:

```
<table> 
<tr>
    <td rowspan=6>A</td>
    <td rowspan=2>B1</td>
    <td rowspan=3>C1</td>
</tr>
<tr><!-- no new cells here --></tr>
<tr><td rowspan=2>B2</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan=3>C2</td></tr>
<tr><td rowspan=2>B3</td></tr>
<tr><!-- no new cells here --></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a nested table? E.g.

```
<table> 
<tr>    
    <td> A
    </td>   
    <td> <table> <tr><td>B1</td></tr> 
                 <tr><td>B2</td></tr> 
                 <tr><td>B3</td></tr> 
        </table>
    </td>
    <td> <table> <tr><td>C1</td></tr> 
                 <tr><td>C2</td></tr> 
        </table>
    </td>                
</tr>     
</table>
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Maybe that was too simple for me to think about it. Thank you very much, kind sir!

Answer (score 1):

Try this visual explanation.  Draw a few examples: (2,8), (4,6), and (3,5), etc.  Get a ruler and extend all the horizontal line segments until they bump up with with the table boundaries.  You'll see that with coprime numbers the horizontal lines won't overlap except at the top and bottom.  Numbers with common factors will cause overlaps, and after drawing a few pictures it should be clear why.

So you have worst case scenario, if you wanted to do (5,7) you'd need 35 rows!  The same happens with any coprime pair.  In this case the different columns are logically like different tables, since their horizontal lines don't mesh at all, except at the top and bottom.

So, pick your poison: a nested table for each 'column' or a cumbersome number of rows glued together awkwardly.

BTW, given (m,n) the answer is not to complicated...